# Record a video resume live to a website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, video

What’s the best way to allow visitors to record a Video Resume live on our site through their webcam and have their videos stored and immediately accessible on their profile page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to capture video is to use a flash widget. It shouldn't be difficult to develop one of these and integrate it as a wordpress plugin.

Alternatively, there are their party widgets and services that can do the heavy lifting for you:

http://nimbb.com/Help/Api.aspx

http://www.seetheface.com/plugins/wordpress/